# Not sure how to approach this pattern in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, null, factory

I have a series of classes that do more or less the same thing. Coming from the Java world I've grouped them under a parent class and am using the Abstract Factory pattern to share common code and provide a single point of creation for my classes. Thus, all classes inherit from DocumentParser which only has pure virtual methods and static methods that create instances of the classes that do the actual work, such as PDFParser.

Each implementation of DocumentParser can only work on one type of document and the constructor will throw an exception if the heuristics fail.

But now I want to add a new kind of factory method that will perform those heuristics and create an instance of the right type of class as necessary. My problem is, what should I do if  I receive a file that does not match any existing parsers? Do I have my factory return `nullptr`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can throw exceptions in C++, that's good!

Comment: Sometimes the answer stares you right in the face. All the way from the question.

Answer (score 1):

It mostly depends on the construction of your code as a whole. Before asking the community, you should ask **yourself**:

> What would I want to do when the user tries to open a file, my app doesn't handle?

And based on the answer, you could do one of the following:

- if the answer is "the user's smart enough to know", then just return a `nullptr`, and let the code inform the user about an exception, or test for a `nullptr` and show your own information prompt,
- if the answer is "that's gonna happen a lot", then you'll probably want to return some abstract reader that will be able to read any file by ignoring the contents and returning an empty file,
- if the code is going to be made into some kind of library, it may be best to just throw an exception

And no matter what you pick - don't blindly chase design patterns. The code should be clear and logical, not pattern-oriented.